# regarding storing user inputs

Tags: java

Some of you may be familiar with this guys youtube channel who takes you through learning java in a very noob friendly manner, this [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DdacOkrTgo&index=6&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28) I am finding them very helpful, most the times when I get some sort of error the answer is already in the comments, this one I couldn't find, this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples{
    public static void main{String args[]){
        Scanner harbo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(harbo.nextLine());
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get when i run it:

Error:

```
Main method not found in class apples, please define the main method as:<br/>
    public static void main(String[] args)

or a JavaFX application class must extend `javafx.application.Application`
```

Sorry if this is really obvious, completely new to Java, just finished learning python ^_^

Comment: Is that really a `{` character you have after `main`?  I think a `(` might work better.

Comment: Hint: always run the compiler on the code you are posting here. Your code says `main {` ... so you are using { instead of ( to start the parameter list. Meaning: this code failed to compile with some completely different message! That is the thing about learning programming: all the subtle details matter. It is better to always double, triple check if the input you are providing to others is really the one giving you trouble!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the answer is already given in the error message.

"please define the main method as":

```
public static void main(String[] args){...}
```

Instead of

```
public static void main{String args[]){...}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token

 at apples.main(apples.java:4)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message tells you what the problem is: you have a JavaFX app and you need to extend the right class to get your code running:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;

class apples extends javafx.application.Application {
    public static void main{String[] args){
        Scanner harbo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(harbo.nextLine());
    }
}
```

And by the way, take care of the naming conventions used in Java, for example class names are CamelCase and start with an uppercase letter. In your case it would be `Apples` instead of `apples`.

Comment: Thank you! sorry really noobie ;P

Comment: Next time you do copy and paste, put it into the compiler ;-)
You just repeated his typo ...

Comment: Thanks but noticed myself too. I'd use a compiler if Java would have a nice command line tool -- currently it is too much overhead ;)

Answer (score 1):

Minor Syntactical error found in your code just use "(" instead of "{" in `main`

```
class apples{
    public static void main (String args[]){ //remove "{" and add "("
         Scanner harbo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(harbo.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks! just started a few hours ago and i'm pretty tired ;D I fixed it all now anyway so i can continue.